# How to sort an array by prioritizing specific attributes

Tags: ruby

So I'm getting records from ActiveRecord and I'd like to do something like:

```
VIP_LIST = ['John', 'Larry', 'Dan']

records = [
 { name: "Adam" },
 { name: "Larry" },
 { name: "John" },
 { name: "Eric" },
 { name: "Dan" }
]

# This is what I want to end up with:

sort_please(records, VIP_LIST)
  => [
   { name: "John" },
   { name: "Larry" },
   { name: "Dan" },
   { name: "Adam" },
   { name: "Eric" }
  ]
```

How can i achieve this?

P.S. There could be values in `VIP_LIST` that are not even in records

Comment: So basically put the records corresponding to the list items first, in order of the list, and then the rest in the original order?

Comment: Use sort with a block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
records.sort_by do |x|
  [VIP_LIST.index(x[:name]) || VIP_LIST.length, records.index(x)]
end

# => [{:name=>"John"}, {:name=>"Larry"}, {:name=>"Dan"}, {:name=>"Adam"}, {:name=>"Eric"}]
```

Comment: That's basically the same as my answer but converted to one line, and missing the bit that keeps the non VIPs in the same order. I think that was part of the requirement, unless I'm mistaken. It's returning Eric and Adam in the reversed order.

Comment: yea. eric and adam are in reverse

Comment: I didn't notice that I had the wrong order in the last, now it should be ok.

Comment: Interesting way of simplifying even further with that last edit. I don't think I've used `||` that way before, but I'll have to remember that.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a clever one liner, but it works:

```
VIP_LIST = ['John', 'Larry', 'Dan', 'Fred']

records = [
 { name: "Adam" },
 { name: "Larry" },
 { name: "John" },
 { name: "Eric" },
 { name: "Dan" }
]

  sorted = records.sort_by do |record|
    name = record[:name]
    if VIP_LIST.include?(name)
      VIP_LIST.index(name)
    else
      records.index(record) + VIP_LIST.length
    end
  end

  p sorted # => [{:name=>"John"}, {:name=>"Larry"}, {:name=>"Dan"}, {:name=>"Adam"}, {:name=>"Eric"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

this one?

```
new_arr = []
VIP_LIST.each do |v|
  new_arr << records.select {|r| r[:name] == v } unless nil?
end
new_arr.flatten!
new_arr = new_arr + (records - new_arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is both clear and concise:

```
vip = records.select{ |hash| VIP_LIST.include? hash[:name] }
vip = vip.sort_by{|x| VIP_LIST.find_index(x[:name])} #reorder vip array
sorted_records = (vip + records).uniq
```

Comment: Nice and short but it's returning Larry before John. I think they're supposed to be in the order listed, unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: Ah yes, I missed the requirement about preserving the order. Thanks.